# Android Kotlin Statement to Java Convert

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am building an App using CameraX API. I'm following [android codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#4) example. In Codelab, The project is written on Kotlin, but in my project, I am using Java. I can't understand how do I convert these statements to java? Even I don't know, what is this line does.

```
// Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
```

Comment: @dominicoder No, I just want to know how is it works. I am not familiar with ```?:```. Thank you.

Comment: @AbuSufianShawon - "No, I just want to know how is it works. I am not familiar with ?:. Thank you." - The only question in your post is literally "I can't understand how do I convert these statements to java?", but OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koltin's null-safety: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

The **?:** in Kotlin is called elvis-operator and it replaces Java's:

```
if (imageCapture == null) {
    return
}
```

The code is checking if imageCapture is null and if so it returns and does not continue to the code below.